# Flurry events are not being logged in Dashboard in ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, flurry

Flurry events are not being logged in flurry dashboard from ios app,

But these events are being logged to flurry dashboard immediately, whenever the user clicks on Device home button.

Comment: your question not clear

Comment: I tracked events in flurry dashboard from ios app, when we perform some events and click on device home button, i,e app goes into background, then only the events are being tracked in flurry dashboard.  if the app is not going to background those events are not being tracked in flurry dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Flurry is designed to work this way.

Flurry reports the events in a single batch when the app is closed with the home button *or* the events are saved to disk and report the next time the app is launched with internet access.

Comment: Thanks, It is helpful. It means that the events are not being logged until the app is closed or relaunched. right?

Comment: Correct. Feel free to email support@flurry.com if you have any further problems with your event integration.

Comment: Sure, Thanks. @ Flurry Support